# How to get remote peer address in C/C++ on Linux of the external process socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, process, ebpf

I'm working on a monitoring project based on ebpf to monitor sockets of the external process on Linux. In case of monitoring server (listener) process, using ebpf hook to accept() syscall I can get the new socket ID created for remote peer.
I need to get a remote peer address of the newly created socket.

I know that `lsof` does processing of `/proc/<pid>/fd` and `/proc/net/tcp` to filter queried items based on the process id.
But so far I don't see how it works on Ubuntu-20 as I don't see matching of socket id from `/proc/<pid>/fd` and listing from `/proc/net/tcp`.

Example :

```
# ls -al /proc/531903/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 dima dima  0 Jul 23 20:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 dima dima  0 Jul 23 20:05 ..
lrwx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 1 -> /dev/pts/4
l-wx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 10 -> 'pipe:[270323787]'
lrwx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 3 -> 'socket:[2947859549]'
lrwx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 4 -> 'socket:[2952899042]'
lr-x------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 5 -> 'pipe:[270323784]'
l-wx------ 1 dima dima 64 Jul 23 20:57 6 -> 'pipe:[270323784]'
```

```
# netstat -ano | grep 44000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45350         127.0.0.1:44000         ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::44000                :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:44000         127.0.0.1:45350         ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

```
# cat /proc/net/tcp | grep ABE
  19: 0100007F:B126 0100007F:ABE0 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 3167851807 1 0000000000000000 20 4 24 10 -1
```

So, `3167851807` is inode from `/proc/net/tcp` output but it doesn't match `'socket:[2952899042]'` from  `ls -al /proc/531903/fd` output.

What I'm missing ?

Second, can `netlink` API be used to query sockets and avoid parsing of `/proc/net/tcp` directory ?

Or is there any other way to get process/socket peer remote address ?

Comment: Recent kernels [allow you to attach an eBPF program on `getpeername()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1b66d253610c7f8f257103808a9460223a087469), you could maybe retrieve the remote address from there?

Comment: I was considering `getpeername()` but I need to pass `sockfd` as the first parameter. And unfortunately I can't do that as hook is executed in a different process and `sockfd` is local virtual id of the process.